# Перемещение объекта в юнити по двум направляющим

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня возник вопрос по перемещению объекта в юнити. У меня есть платформа которая может ездить по 2 направлающим(одна в носе платформы, друга сзади). И вот в чем вопрос мне нужно что бы когда ты опускал заднюю часть платформы что бы передняя была неподвижной, и наоборот. То есть одновременно происходит два действия перемещение и вращение. Может кто знает как это реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

2 GameObject'а которые можно двигать (направляющие)
2 GameObject'а на самой платформе
скрипт выравнивает все 4 точки в одну линию

если хочешь чтобы платформа не висела "в воздухе" между направляющими
хотя бы одна из точек платформы должна быть закреплена на направляющей